# npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/node_modules/cordova.git

Tags: node.js, git, cordova, github

I can't run the `npm install` command it keeps providing me with this error:

```
Error while executing:
/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/node_modules/cordova.git

ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

exited with error code: 128
```

This github link is not found:

```
git@github.com/node_modules/cordova.git
```

I've tried uninstalling then reinstalling `node` & `npm` but still getting the same error message

Any reasons as to why?

**UPDATE**

The issue was cordova, updating cordova fixed this issue `npm i cordova@latest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure `ssh -T git@github.com` does work, meaning you do have the relevant id_rsa(.pub) SSH keys created and registered.

Second, check your full `npm install` command (ie the parameter you put *after* `npm install`), since https://github.com/node_modules/cordova does not exist, and https://github.com/node_modules neither.

Try a

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova@latest
```

Although using the latest version was problematic before: [issue 28](https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard/issues/28)

The OP confirms:

> The issue was cordova, updating cordova fixed this issue: `npm i cordova@latest`

Comment: Ok that actually solves the issue the `npm uninstall -g cordova`

But I run into errors now when building a platform.

The `FormData()` doesn't accept numbers on the `body.append()`

Comment: I guess the updated `FormData()` changes the allowed values in the latest cordova version?

Comment: @EfosaSylvesterOmorogbe That is possible (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28047683/6309)

Comment: @EfosaSylvesterOmorogbe But that would be best addressed as a new question